# msbuild fails with successful robocopy exit code

Tags: msbuild, robocopy

My msbuild script fails even if copying files is successful. If robocopy command exitcode < 8, it means that files copied. So how can I say to msbuild script IgnoreExitCode if exit code < 8?
I set IgnoreExitCode to true, but what if it's real error?

```
<Exec Command="robocopy  $(SourceDir) $(DestinationDir) /mir /mt /xd $(ExcludeDir)" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Use **ExitCode** output parameter  of **Exec** task and **ContinueOnError** parameter instead of **IgnoreExitCode**:

```
<Exec ContinueOnError="True" Command="robocopy  $(SourceDir) $(DestinationDir) /mir /mt /xd $(ExcludeDir)">
   <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
</Exec>
<Error Condition="$(ErrorCode) &gt; 7" Message="Robocopy failed"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [this workaround](https://superuser.com/a/346112/500):

```
(robocopy  $(SourceDir) $(DestinationDir) /mir /mt /xd $(ExcludeDir)) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 exit 0
```